# Python running elif block, when the if block is true

Tags: python, if-statement

Why did the elif statement execute even though the if was already true

```
s=input("Enter the string: ")
c=3
while True:
    if s[0]=="a":
        s=s[2:]
    elif s[-1]=="b":
        s=s[:2]
    else:
        c+=1
        break
    print(s)
    print(c)
```

Output:

```
Enter the string: aaccbb
ccbb
3
cc
3
```

Comment: It didn't, first iteration the if is true, second iteration the if is false and end the elif is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only running *one* of the choices in the `if` statement, but it's making that decision *multiple* times because you're looping:

- The `if` block runs on the first iteration of the loop because the string is `aabbcc`. This changes the string to `ccbb`.
- On the second iteration, the string is now `ccbb` so the `elif` block runs and changes the string to `cc`.
- The third iteration has the string `cc` so the `else` block runs and you therefore break from the loop.

At *no* stage does a *single* iteration of the loop have the `if` statement executing more than one choice.